# Rank of a matrix in a matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose $E$ is a $m \times n$ matrix of rank $n$, ($n < m$). $F$ is another matrix of order $n \times m$ such that
$$
FE = I_n
$$
where $I_n$ is the Identity matrix of order $n$. My question: is it necessary that $\mathrm{rank}(F) = n$?

Comment: Yes: $\operatorname{rank} (FE) \leq \min\{\operatorname{rank} F, \operatorname{rank} E\}$.

Comment: Thank you. From the above observation is it true that the condition $rank(E) = n$ is not necessary for the assertion to hold true?

Comment: It is necessary: We have $n = \operatorname{rank} I_n = \operatorname{rank} (FE) \leq \min\{\operatorname{rank} F, \operatorname{rank} E\} \leq \operatorname{rank} E \leq \min\{m, n\} = n$.

Comment: But by the same token one could argue that $$n = \mathrm{rank } I_n = \mathrm{rank}(FE)\leq \mathrm{min}\{\mathrm{rank } F, \mathrm{rank }E \} \leq \mathrm{rank} F \leq \mathrm{min}\{n, m\} = n.$$

Comment: That's true, and in fact essentially the intended resolution of my hint.